# Javascript onclick in textbox always returns me value 0 for my first click into the box

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and just learning the fundamentals. Wanted to build a Fahrenheit to Celsius vice versa calculator. I ran into the issue, that every time I first click into the textbox, before I even type in a value, it automatically recognizes a value "0" and converts 0 into Celsius. I want that the calculation process only starts when numbers with the keyboard are typed in. Is there maybe anyway how to ignore clicks or just to address the input of the keyboard so that it doesn't calculate the 0.

```js
function calculate(fahrenheit){

    fahrenheit = document.getElementById("convertToFahrenheit").value;

    document.getElementById("convertToCelsius").value =  Math.round((fahrenheit -32) * 5 / 9);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>  
    <input id= "convertToFahrenheit" type="text" placeholder="Fahrenheit" onclick="calculate()"></input>

    <input id="convertToCelsius" type="text" placeholder="Celsius" onclick=""></input>

  </body>

</html>
```

I really have no clue how to fix that, as I am a beginner.

Comment: thats because you are using `onclick` to call your function so as soon as you click on your input it will call your function despite the fact that you didn't type anything yet. Instead of using an `onclick` on the HTML you should make use of `addEventListener` and use something like `change` or `blur` to start your calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're experiencing is due to the fact that you've attached the calculate() function to the click event of the input field. This means that the function will be triggered whenever the input field is clicked, even if no value has been entered yet. To achieve the behavior you're looking for (calculate only when numbers are typed in), you can use the input event instead of the click event. Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="convertToFahrenheit" type="text" placeholder="Fahrenheit" oninput="calculate()"></input>
    <input id="convertToCelsius" type="text" placeholder="Celsius"></input>
    <script>
      function calculate() {
        let fahrenheit = document.getElementById("convertToFahrenheit").value;
        if (fahrenheit !== "") {
          document.getElementById("convertToCelsius").value = Math.round((parseFloat(fahrenheit) - 32) * 5 / 9);
        } else {
          document.getElementById("convertToCelsius").value = "";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If any problem reply me.

Comment: just wondering what was wrong with putting the parameter 'fahrenheit' inside the brackets of the function. is it better do it with let in the first line of the function instead of the brackets

Comment: @meowalarm you are not sending any parameter when you call your function in your `onclick` `onclick="calculate()"` and also there is no point sending any parameter at all if you are going to overwrite it anyway again with this line here `fahrenheit = document.getElementById("convertToFahrenheit").value;` You have to either send the element as parameter and don't reference that element anymore inside your function or don't send any parameter at all and get the element after you call your function

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are using an `onclick` to call your function so everytime you click on the input, it will call the function despite the fact that you didn't have the chance to type anything yet.

You should avoid using `onclick` on the HTML and make use of `addEventListener` instead

```js
const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll("input"); //reference both inputs
inputElements.forEach(ele => { //loop thru them
  ele.addEventListener("change", function() { //addEvent
    if (ele.id == "convertToFahrenheit") {
      //if statement to avoid getting NaN in the celsius input in case you delete what you previously typed
      if (ele.value != '') {
        document.getElementById("convertToCelsius").value = Math.round((parseFloat(ele.value) - 32) * 5 / 9);
      } else {
        document.getElementById("convertToCelsius").value = "";
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementById("convertToCelsius").value = "";
      //in case later you want to also type something in the celsius input and convert it to Fahrenheit, you can add that logic here
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<input id="convertToFahrenheit" type="text" placeholder="Fahrenheit">
<input id="convertToCelsius" type="text" placeholder="Celsius">
```